# Export contents as csv in Drupal 8

Tags: export-to-csv, drupal-8

Have added new repository items and filled all the fields with appropriate details. I wish to export this content as CSV, XML so that changes can be made in the downloaded CSV file and then import this CSV or sync automatically with the uploaded content type.
How do I proceed?

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=95&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have tried hands-on various modules available online, out of which the VBO export module seemed to be working. But encountered an AJAX 200 error. 

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /batch?id=95&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: